# Google App Engine Static Files GET 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

The following app.yaml works great on my local dev server.. but when I deploy it to production all static files throw 404. Server isn't able to locate any static files. Have been searching for hours couldn't find a valid solution.

Note: I am developing with mac, so aware of the case sensitive nature of the system.

```
application: dev-scanner
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: static_files/\1
  upload: ./static_files/(.+)

- url: /
  static_files: static_files/index.html
  upload: ./static_files/index.html
```

Here is the error from the log

> 2011-03-18 01:18:07.033 / 404 21ms
>   0cpu_ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U;
>   Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US)
>   AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/10.0.648.134
>   Safari/534.16,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)
>   76.126.174.202 - - [18/Mar/2011:01:18:07 -0700] "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6;
>   en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.134
>   Safari/534.16,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)"
>   "dev.app-scanner.com" ms=21 cpu_ms=0
>   api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000053 W
>   2011-03-18 01:18:07.012 Static file
>   referenced by handler not found:
>   static_files/index.html

Here is the file system structure after I use `appcfg.py download_app -A`

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change `static_files` on the yaml to `static_dir`?

Comment: `./` is redundant.  I'm not sure it's causing your problem, but I'd try removing it.

Comment: I'm a bit late, but I'd like to note that I had the same problem with a different solution. For future readers: double check to make sure your includes and your file names match up exactly (INCLUDING case). I was developing on Windows (sorry) and thought `image.PNG` would be recognized the same as `image.png`, but GAE's environment distinguishes between the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the app.yaml in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/873098

It successfully serves a static site.  The main differences I see are the lack of the './' as noted by @Wooble above, and the use of (.*) instead of (.+) as the main regular expression. (.+) should work in theory though.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thank you Calvin, this app.yaml was very helpful and covers all the cases. @Jorge @Wooble, Thanks for the help folks