# Octopress, Google AppEngine (GAE) and app.yaml - getting 404

Tags: git, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, octopress

I'm trying to publish a blog created with Octopress on GAE, but I'm constantly getting a 404.

This is my app.yaml:

```
application: salattinet
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
# index files
- url: /(.*)/
  static_files: public/\1/index.html
  upload: public/(.+)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

# index files
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: public/\1/index.html
  upload: public/(.*)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

- url: /blog/(.*)
  static_files: public/blog/\1/index.html
  upload: public/blog/(.+)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

- url: /
```

Everything works fine locally, and the public folder is indeed called public.

[This](http://pastebin.com/YR5bc8MJ) is the folder structure (pastebin).

I'm deploying using Push-to-Deploy (git).

GAE log looks like this:

```
2013-07-21 11:35:11.322 / 404 65ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
80.167.172.136 - - [21/Jul/2013:02:35:11 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36" "salattinet.appspot.com" ms=65 cpu_ms=0 app_engine_release=1.8.2 
W 2013-07-21 11:35:11.321
Static file referenced by handler not found: public/index.html
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349671/google-app-engine-static-files-get-404) and the mentioned gist, but that didn't help.

**Edit**

For some reason publishing with:

```
appcfg.py --oauth2 update .
```

...works. Probably it has something to do with how the folder structure is published by the script as opposed to git. Still trying to figure out why, and how to make Push-to-Deploy works.

Comment: This isn't a proper answer to your question, so I'll put it in a comment. I recommend using Amazon S3 buckets for hosting Octopress blogs. It's a great solution - cheap as dirt, you get a CDN built in, and you don't need any kind of routing engine since they are purely static documents. You can even host a root domain now on S3, so no more worries about needing a "www" subdomain. And support for S3 is easy using s3cmd in a rake task. Github pages are also a good option.

Comment: I think I will follow your suggestion...

Comment: If it helps, here's a gist showing how I use s3cmd to deploy Octopress to S3: https://gist.github.com/bashcoder/24af831cafb59589efc3